# How to prevent re-rendering on onChange Event of input field

Tags: reactjs, typescript

/**

- Make sure we keep the same functionality, without causing a re-render
- on every keypress when typing in the input.

*/
import React, { useState } from "react";

```
export const Example: React.FC = () => {

  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");

  function handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setUserInput(event.target.value);
  }

  console.log("Example renders");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Send us some feedback</h1>
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={userInput} />
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={() => {
            alert(userInput);
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is a controlled input. Its value is fed from the state. If the value in state is not changing, then the value of the input will not change

Comment: it's normal, thats how react works

Comment: Why don't you want the component to re-render with the updated value?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you want to prevent re-rendering for performance reasons - don't worry about it as React is well optimised to make the re-render seamless (unless you are going to be introducing further logic that you have not shared with us in your example)